# Variables in ssl_certificate and ssl_certificate_key are not working

Tags: nginx, server

I want to dynamically load different SSL certificates depend on user agent. According to [nginx documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_certificate), it has option to use variables in ssl_certificate and ssl_certificate_key directives.

However when I tried that on my server (nginx 1.23.1, openssl 1.1.1n), it seems not to work - variables are empty, according to error log, but nginx varialbes (like $host) are working fine.

Here is example of my config:

```
set $ssl_cert /etc/letsencrypt/live/redacted.com/fullchain.pem;
set $ssl_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/redacted.com/privkey.pem;
ssl_certificate $ssl_cert;
ssl_certificate_key $ssl_key;
```

nginx works fine with this config, but when i try to open site, it returns ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR, and in error.log i got message "cannot load certificate "/etc/nginx/"" (seems like variable is empty).

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the variable `$ssl_ Key` requires a `.key` file, but here is a `.pem` file.

```
set $ssl_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/redacted.com/privkey.pem;
```

Maybe, it should be：

```
<your path prefix>/privkey.key;
```

According to the prompt: Please provide a `.key` file and check the file path.